# How to update issued at and expiry claims on each token call using Go Oauth2 library?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, jwt

Using the OAuth2 Client Credentials package ([here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/clientcredentials))  I've requesting access tokens that expire after 60 minutes. When they expire the client just reuses the config to apply for another token (because the JWT flow response doesn't include a refresh token).

The issue I'm having is the config has had the exp and iat claims set on initial authorisation.

Claims compiled code:

```
claims = &jws.ClaimSet{
        Iss: Iss,
        Aud: tokenURL,
        Exp: time.Now().Add(time.Second * 45).Unix(),
        Iat: time.Now().Unix(),
        Sub: Sub,
        Prn: "",
        PrivateClaims: map[string]interface{}{
            "aud":          tokenURL,
            "jti":          val,
        },
    }
```

and then the client is initialised with

```
    privateKey, err := decryptPrivateKey(AppSettings)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to configure private key: %v", err)
    }
    claims, err := createJWTClaims(AppSettings, Type)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create claims: %v", err)
    }
    signingHeaders := createHeader(AppSettings)

    // Assemble payload params
    payload, err := jws.Encode(signingHeaders, claims, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to encode payload")
    }

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
    v.Add("assertion", payload)

    config := &clientcredentials.Config{
        ClientID:       ClientID,
        ClientSecret:   ClientSecret,
        TokenURL:       tokenURL,
        Scopes:         nil,
        EndpointParams: v,
        AuthStyle:      1,
    }

    client := config.Client(context.Background())
```

Is there anyway to have the values set in `v` update on call, or point towards a variable that gets captured on use?

Edit: To rephrase the question, is there any Go method I'm missing that would allow me to have the claim within `v` update on call? Or alternatively, if the only solution to this to customise the TokenSource call?